# Count occurrences in many to many

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database i have following tables:

```
Person (
id,
name,
agentId
)

Agent (
id,
title
)

Agency (
id,
name
)

AgentAgency (
id,
agentId,
agencyId
)
```

I need query that will get all info about Person -> Agents with extra attribute numberOfAgencies that will show number of agencies of each agent, AND i need to show one more attribute agencyName that will show me name of first or only agency that user have (i need it in case agent have only 1 agency).

I tried something like this but without any success.

```
 SELECT *, COUNT (aa.agentId) as numberOfAgencies
 FROM agentAgencies as aa
 LEFT JOIN agent as a ON a.id = aa.agentId
 LEFT JOIN agency as ag ON aa.agencyId= ag.id
 LEFT JOIN person as p ON p.id = ag.personId
 GROUP BY ag.id, aa.id, p.id, a.id
```

For example i expect response like this: 
PersonName John, AgencyName Cool Agency, numberOfAgencies 4

Comment: Show what you tried.  Preferably together with all necessary CREATE TABLE statements, so that someone can copy-paste on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and start working on it right away.  Also define what you mean by "without any success".  Also, what is it?  mysql or postgresql?  Pick ***one***.

Comment: MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: Are you sure the AgentAgency has the right columns? By it's naming I would expect that it is a join table between Agent and Agency. Is the column agentId there instead of personId?

Comment: Yea that is correct, my mistake, i updated my question with sql sample, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `agent` as first table in the FROM clause

Comment: To construct the best performing query, it's necessary to know whether your referential columns are nullable or not.  For example, is it possible for Agent.personId to be NULL?  This affects whether you use OUTER or INNER JOINs, and whether you use sub-queries as well

Comment: I updated my question, i made huge mistake and i noticed minute ago, in Person table i have agentId, and agentId can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
MAX(p.Name) PersonName,
count(a.id) NoOfAgencies,
MAX(a.name) AgencyName
FROM persons p
LEFT OUTER JOIN agent g ON g.Id=p.agentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN AgentAgency aa ON aa.agentId = g.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Agency a on a.id = aa.agencyId
GROUP BY a.Id
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, i will run this query and check if it works

Comment: `count(*)` will return `1` if an agent has no agency.

Comment: This is awesome. I was thinking of doing subquery that just returns the count where a.id = aa.id, but didn't know you could do a MAX on a string

Comment: You should replace `count(*)` with `count(aa.personid)`

Comment: I've updated to count(a.id), but count(aa.id) should also work

Comment: I just noticed that i made huge mistake, i changed my question can you please read it one more time, so basically i have in Person table with agentId.